# Firefox randomly won't start - Ongoing investigation

Tags: windows, boot, firefox, 64-bit

I'm going insane with this problem.

I cannot create an account at mozilla. They are idiots now. I click "forgot password" "forgot username" whatever, I never get the email from them to retrieve it. And gone is the option to create a new account. I simply cannot communicate with them and they seem to not care anymore about users. They routinely give the same canned response to every user (Refresh Firefox my ass).

Anyway.

The problem I have is random. It sometimes works. But 90% of the time Firefox doesn't launch so it's maddening!

I will try to be clear:

Firefox fails to launch a window for the user to actually browse. But it does create a firefox.exe process (taks manager) and **WHEN IT WILL FAIL, THE PROCESS IS ALWAYS 17,000K in RAM** (17,000 TO 17,999). Every single time!!

If I keep on clicking. It creates more and more firefox processes of that size!

IT WILL eventually create one that works and launches a window.

The process **WILL work** (launch a freakin' window) **IF it's either lower than 17k and "rises" or if it's higher than that**. RAM usage climbs to 300MB to 700MB when it works correctly.

I HOPE someone else can understand what is going on so I can just use the damn browser. Chrome sucks.

I tried clean installs, profiles, safe-booting. It does the same. It did the same after a complete Windows reinstall (I mean from scratch) that I did months ago.

I'm using Windows 7 x64.

I tried attaching a capture of Task Manager with the two firefox.exe processes. One that failed and one that worked.

ALSO...
I'm still investigating all of this. I want others with the same problem to benefit from this too.

I notice that whenever there's a software like Winamp, Sony Vegas or Media Player HC running, this problem happens without fail. I THINK that it NEVER happens if those are not running... Will report back on that.

Thank you very much for your time.

[Firefox multiple processes of 17,000K of RAM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcMjM.png)

Comment: This problem sometimes happens to me if I already have Firefox open and the process is taking up a lot of RAM (over 1 GB) and not much RAM is free in the system.  Then when I click the Firefox icon to open another window, it might not actually launch a new window - it'll just create another small firefox.exe process and do nothing.  At this point I'll just kill all the firefox processes and relaunch it and restore my session.

Comment: I see. Not my case. 

I have 8GB of RAM and Firefox never uses too much. In fact, I end up with 3-6 firefox.exe processes that only take 17MB each. 
Thanks for your input.